# Upload all projects to one github repository

Tags: android, git, github

I have several projects on my laptop. I would like to upload all of them to GitHub and in one repository called Android-projects. After searching the web and being bombarded by different material I got confused. How can I do that? I didn't quite understand the answers found on this website. All my attempts failed.

I have GitHub Desktop and Git Shell installed on my laptop, but don't know how to use them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing much to do there:

1. Create an empty directory and add it to git or create a project on github and clone it to get the empty directory
2. Add your projects one by one to that directory and checkin

NOTE: Tracking changes will become a bit tedious with this appropriate. You will need to be careful if you are working on multiple projects at the same time.

Comment: I have created local repository. There are gitignore and gitattributes files. It is located on C:\Users\Marat\Documents\GitHub\Android-Projects my android projects are on C:\Users\Marat\AndroidStudioProjects. What I need to do next?

Comment: now create a project on GitHub, add the files and checkin

Comment: I don't know how to create a project on GitHub. I have uploaded photo of what I have now on GitHub desktop application

Comment: I have pressed publish on app then I have a repository created on my account on web. It contains the same files

Answer (score 1):

In the main project folder where all your android projects are present, initialize a git repository there. `git init`

now [create a repository on github](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/).

Finally, a[dd (push) your code to github](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/).